# Python Optparse list

Tags: python, optparse

I'm using the python optparse module in my program, and I'm having trouble finding an easy way to parse an option that contains a list of values.

For example:

```
--groups one,two,three.
```

I'd like to be able to access these values in a list format as `options.groups[]`. Is there an optparse option to convert comma separated values into a list? Or do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Look at [option callbacks](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse#option-callbacks).  Your callback function can parse the value into a list using a basic `optarg.split(',')`

Answer (score 84):

S.Lott's answer has already been accepted, but here's a code sample for the archives:

```
def foo_callback(option, opt, value, parser):
  setattr(parser.values, option.dest, value.split(','))

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-f', '--foo',
                  type='string',
                  action='callback',
                  callback=foo_callback)
```

Answer (score 12):

Again, just for the sake of archive completeness, expanding the example above:

- You can still use "dest" to specify the option name for later access
- Default values cannot be used in such cases (see explanation in [Triggering callback on default value in optparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568141/triggering-callback-on-default-value-in-optparse))
- If you'd like to validate the input, OptionValueError should be thrown from foo_callback

The code (with tiny changes) would then be:

```
def get_comma_separated_args(option, opt, value, parser):
    setattr(parser.values, option.dest, value.split(','))

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-f', '--foo',
                  type='string',
                  action='callback',
                  callback=get_comma_separated_args,
                  dest = foo_args_list)
```

Answer (score 10):

With optparse, to get a list value you can use action '**append**':

> ```
> from optparse import OptionParser
> parser = OptionParser()
> parser.add_option("--group",
>                   action="append",
>                   dest="my_groups")
> (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
> print options.my_groups
> ```

Then call your program like this:

**$ python demo.py --group one --group two --group three**

['one', 'two', 'three']